# Why this code is getting slower when I use std::algorithms instead of plain loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, runtime

I am calculating the mean and standard deviation of the elements of a vector. I have two versions of this and I am completely puzzled why the version using the standard algorithms is slower than the one using plain loops.

Both version use this struct as return type:

```
struct MeanAndSigma {
    double mean;
    double sigma;
};
```

And the version with loops is this:

```
MeanAndSigma getMeanAndSigma(const DVector& v){
    MeanAndSigma ms;
    ms.mean = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();++i){ms.mean += v[i];}
    ms.mean = ms.mean / v.size();
    double sqsum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();++i){sqsum += (v[i]-ms.mean)*(v[i]-ms.mean);}
    ms.sigma = std::sqrt(sqsum / (v.size()-1));   
    return ms;
}
```

And the one with algorithms:

```
MeanAndSigma getMeanAndSigma2(const DVector& v){
    MeanAndSigma ms;
    ms.mean = std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0.0) / v.size();
    DVector diff(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),diff.begin(),
             std::bind2nd(std::minus<double>(), ms.mean));
    double sqsum = std::inner_product(diff.begin(),diff.end(),diff.begin(),0.0);
    ms.sigma = std::sqrt(sqsum / (v.size()-1));
    return ms;
}
```

When I measure the time they take per 10k calls with a vector with 10k elements I get ~2.0 seconds for the version with loops and ~3.2 seconds for the one with algorithms. Why is this?

I already compared cpu time and real time, but it seems as if both are running (as expected) on a single cpu. Am I doing something stupidly wrong in using the algorithms?

EDIT: I am not claiming, that the two versions are equivalent. Nevertheless I would have expected that the second version would be faster. As pointed out in comments and an answer, the second version uses an extra iteration over the elements and an extra `DVector` (which is btw just a `typedef std::vector<double>`). However, I am not familiar enough with the standard algorithms to improve the second version. So, now my question is:

**How can I improve the version with algorithms to be faster than the one using plain loops?**

Comment: Are you running with optimizations enabled, as code like the second function benefits massively from optimizations. If you're not running with optimizations enabled then time measurements are mainly meaningless.

Comment: @MikeVine Yes, I use compiler optimizations. It is g++ 4.9.1 and I am compiling with `-O3`

Comment: `getMeanAndSigma2` is using `DVector diff` which allocate memory and `std::transform` is doing more stuff. The two functions are not *equal*

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, you are right, but I dont know how to merge this two into a single statement.

Comment: @Mine I already know that they are not equal. One is using loops, the other algorithms. One takes more time than the other, so they are obviously not doing the same calculations. But I am missing some understanding to make the one with algorithms more efficient.

Comment: @tobi303 That’s begging the question then. Of course the loops are faster, they do less work (they don’t allocate a large vector, for starters). The *real* question should have been “how do I implement this calculation using standard algorithms?” Incidentally, that’s a very good question — [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) could help.

Comment: `inner_product` has an overload that takes 2 custom binary operations. You could use that to avoid the `vector` allocation and `transform` call. Something like this - `double sqsum = std::inner_product(diff.begin(), diff.end(), diff.begin(), 0.0, std::plus<double>(), [&ms](double d1, double d2) { return (d1 - ms.mean) * (d2 - ms.mean); });` (untested)

Comment: @tobi303 Basically, `getMeanAndSigma` takes 2 loops of the vector, while `getMeanAndSigma2` takes 3 loops, I think that's the root cause.

Comment: @Praetorian I cannot use C++11, and I think lambdas are not available "pre 11"

Comment: @tobi303 Replace it with a `struct` that has a `double operator()(double, double) const` operator then

Comment: @Mine: In fact the second solution takes *4* loops, because `diff`'s constructor initialises all of its `v.size()` entries.

Comment: @tobi303: Your latest piece of code calculates the wrong thing -- `XYZ::operator()()` needs to *add* the new computed value to the existing total in `d1`!  gkamal's code is correct.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, I just noticed it. I was too focused on getting it running somehow that I didnt pay attention to what I was actually calculating. Still I dont understand why this last piece of (nonsense) code needs so much more time, but I guess that is going a bit off topic...

Comment: @j_random_hacker just in case you care: I fixed it to calculate the correct value and suddenly it takes same time as gkamal's version. As it is just a dupe of his code I will remove it from the question again. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @tobi303: I don't know why either, since it seems to have the same number of operations!  So is gkamal's (and now your) code now taking the same time with the std::algorithms approach as with a plain loop?  Or is it still slower?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I now get for the same test case ~2 seconds for loops and the algorithm version. The algorithm version seems to be slightly faster, but I do not want to dig too deep into high accuracy time measurement, thus the difference is to small to be significant for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working faster :)  A possible explanation for the slight speed increase of the algorithm version: I once looked at the generated assembly in a similar situation, and found to my amazement that (with the compiler and platform I was using) looping through a `vector` with an `int` index variable results in an integer *multiplication* instruction for each boundary test!  Using iterators OTOH did not.  My guess is that something similar is happening here -- and that if you replaced your `int i` with iterators, you would get identical timings.

Comment: Remember, the purpose of any standard utility class or function is not necessarily to be faster than anything you could write. Its purpose is to do the job right with minimum effort on your part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the programs are equivalent.  In the second version (using algorithms) a new vector of doubles is being populated and an extra iteration is also involved.

You could try this (c++11 version), it is equivalent of the first version.  I haven't tried running it, it should work with some minor changes.

```
MeanAndSigma getMeanAndSigma2(const DVector& v){
    MeanAndSigma ms;
    ms.mean = std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0.0) / v.size();
    double sqsum = std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),
       [ms](double sum, double ve){ return sum + (ve-ms.mean)*(ve-ms.mean);}
    );
    ms.sigma = std::sqrt(sqsum / (v.size()-1));
    return ms;
}
```

Without lambdas (not tested, might need some minor changes)

```
class DiffSquare
{
    public:
        DiffSquare(double m) : _m(m) {}
        double operator()(double sum, double e)
        {
            return sum + (e - _m) * (e - _m);   
        }
    private:
        double _m;
};

MeanAndSigma getMeanAndSigma2(const DVector& v) {
    MeanAndSigma ms;
    ms.mean = std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0.0) / v.size();
    DiffSquare diff_square(ms.mean);
    double sqsum = std::accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),
        0.0,
        diff_square
    );
    ms.sigma = std::sqrt(sqsum / (v.size()-1));
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: how would you fix that?

Comment: @tobi303: You could use `std::accumulate()` a second time instead of `std::transform()`, providing your own `BinaryOperation` functor that does the additional calculation before adding it to the total.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that I cannot use C++11.

Comment: However, praetorian already pointed me into some direction how to do it without C++11. I just want to try it, but then I think I will accept your answer, as the question does not say anything about C++11 or not

Comment: added the non lambda version,

Comment: when i try to compile it i get an error "...double(double,double) is not a class,struct or union type...."

Comment: Fixed it, the code compiles now.  It should also work.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried, and it works: needs same time as the loop version. Actually a bit less but not significantly. I still dont understand, why my latest version performs so bad (see last edit). However, problem solved :)